# IIS returning 500 Internal Server Error for POST but working for GET- Flask

Tags: python, flask, iis

I am facing an issue with my flask program.
I hosted a flask application on IIS running on Win 11. But from Postman I am Getting Get response but 500 error when Methos = POST.

But there is no error when running the same code from VS Code.

My Flask code:

```
import decodedata
import Call_printer
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/print',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def printer():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req_data = request.json
        print(req_data)
        data = req_data['data']
        printername= req_data['printername']
        xml = decodedata.decode_xml(data)
        msg = Call_printer.sendprintjob(printername,xml)
        status={"Status":msg}
        return jsonify(status)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "Hello World."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Below is an error when running from IIS.
[Error in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSIs0.png)

Below is the correct POST Response from VS CODE
[Success in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJFVA.png)

But I am receiving responses in GET method from IIS. Only for POST, I am receiving 500 error?
Can it be because I am calling other py files for POST?

Any idea how can I fix it?

Regards,
Mayank Pande

Comment: Is the URL should be `http://localhost:5000/print`?

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error.